# Tools to help create a PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, graphics, printing, printdocument

I have a PrintDocument and its **PrintPage** event tied to a function that uses the **Graphics** object to draw to the page.

But this is very tedious. I have some company data in a settings file that I need to put on the page in a nicely  formatted manner, you know, upper left is the logo, upper right is the date and then some more data in the middle...

Currently, here is how I do it:

```
private void handlePrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Foo", font, brush, new PointF(10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Bar", font, brush, new PointF(10, 30));
}
```

Now its not exactly like that, I have some variables like **pageWidth**, **pageHeight** that I can divide by 2 and print on the centre of the document or to the far right etc. etc.

But again, this is *so* tedious. Is there any better way to get data on a page for printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Word via COM, pretty easy, no calculations required, also, just use a template and you can treat the document as some sort of array :)

This is a really good article and i have used it with Office 2010 even if its pretty old:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Hope it helps :)